# JQM 1.4 svg and png icons nightmare for Offline Apps. Any shortcut?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

As you may know JQM 1.4.1. now include two sets of icons: PNG and SVG. In previous versions all icons were contained in single files (like: icons-18-black.png), which was easy AND SHORT to include in the HTML5 manifes for caching and offline use.

My question is:

Should I declare each one of the icons provided in my html5 cache manifest? including PNGs and SVG?

What if I just declare only PNGs?. Will my JQM Offline App still work or will crash for not being able to find SVGs?

If so, My HTML5 Manifest will grow as long as:

```
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/action-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/action-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/alert-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/alert-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-l-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-l-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-r-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-r-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-d-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-l-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-l-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-r-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-r-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-l-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-l-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-r-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-r-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/arrow-u-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/audio-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/audio-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/back-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/back-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/bars-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/bars-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/bullets-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/bullets-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/calendar-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/calendar-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/camera-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/camera-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-d-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-d-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-l-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-l-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-r-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-r-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-u-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/carat-u-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/check-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/check-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/clock-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/clock-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/cloud-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/cloud-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/comment-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/comment-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/delete-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/delete-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/edit-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/edit-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/eye-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/eye-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/forbidden-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/forbidden-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/forward-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/forward-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/gear-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/gear-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/grid-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/grid-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/heart-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/heart-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/home-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/home-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/info-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/info-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/location-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/location-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/lock-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/lock-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/mail-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/mail-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/minus-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/minus-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/navigation-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/navigation-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/phone-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/phone-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/plus-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/plus-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/power-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/power-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/recycle-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/recycle-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/refresh-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/refresh-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/search-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/search-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/shop-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/shop-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/star-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/star-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/tag-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/tag-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/user-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/user-white.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/video-black.png
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-png/video-white.png
```

REPEATED FOR SVGs.......    :(

```
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/action-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/action-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/alert-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/alert-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-l-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-l-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-r-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-r-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-d-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-l-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-l-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-r-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-r-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-l-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-l-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-r-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-r-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/arrow-u-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/audio-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/audio-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/back-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/back-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/bars-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/bars-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/bullets-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/bullets-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/calendar-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/calendar-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/camera-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/camera-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-d-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-d-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-l-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-l-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-r-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-r-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-u-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/carat-u-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/check-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/check-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/clock-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/clock-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/cloud-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/cloud-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/comment-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/comment-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/delete-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/delete-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/edit-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/edit-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/eye-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/eye-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/forbidden-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/forbidden-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/forward-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/forward-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/gear-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/gear-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/grid-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/grid-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/heart-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/heart-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/home-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/home-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/info-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/info-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/location-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/location-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/lock-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/lock-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/mail-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/mail-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/minus-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/minus-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/navigation-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/navigation-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/phone-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/phone-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/plus-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/plus-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/power-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/power-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/recycle-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/recycle-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/refresh-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/refresh-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/search-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/search-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/shop-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/shop-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/star-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/star-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/tag-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/tag-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/user-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/user-white.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/video-black.svg
http://www.MySite/tablet/jquery/mobile_141/images/icons-svg/video-white.svg
```

And if so. My Offline APP delays more than 1 minute transfering these files to a Sansung Galaxy 3.

THIS IS TOO MUCH TIME FOR MY USERS!!!

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same problem as you. As it turns out those svg images are not actually used and you don't need to include them. The svg images are encoded inline inside the css file.

For my purposes I only need to support browsers that have support for inline svg so I don't need to include either the png files or the svg files in my manifest. Support for inline svg is pretty good: http://caniuse.com/svg-html5

So maybe you can get away with this too.

This whole somewhat confusing scenario is summed up very well in a post at this [link](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/newbie-jquery-mobile-1-4-icons) but I've copied and pasted the relevant bits here for easy reference.

> The standard jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.0.css includes the SVG icons
>   internally in the CSS file, but references the images directory for
>   the PNG files.
>
> - jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css is just the concatenation of the standard Icon, Theme, and Structure CSS files.
> - jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.0.css is a combined file that references PNG files from the images directory. It doesn't use SVG
>     icons at all.
> - jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.0.css is a combined file that includes the PNG icons internally in the CSS file. It does not need the images
>     directory. It also doesn't use SVG icons at all.
> - jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.0.css is a combined file that includes the SVG icons internally in the CSS file. It doesn't use PNG icons at
>     all.
> - Other combinations are possible, either by loading CSS parts separately, or doing a simple concatenation yourself. It's a matter of
>     deciding if you want to support SVG, PNG, or both (fallback to PNG
>     when SVG not supported by browser) and whether you want to include
>     images inline in the CSS file itself or reference them from the images
>     directory.
> - The default combo file makes the most sense in most cases. The SVG icons are loaded inline within the CSS file. These are the icons that
>     are used by most browsers. If the user has a browser that doesn't
>     support SVG, then they've wastefully downloaded unneeded bytes in the
>     CSS file. But this will affect only a very small number of users. In
>     that case, PNG icons will be loaded from the images directory. It
>     wouldn't make sense to burden the vast majority of users by needlessly
>     including the PNG icons inline within the CSS file.
> - Interestingly although the individual SVG icons are included in images/svg, there is no supplied CSS that references them.

Comment: Let me see if I understood, did you mean that All icons are just included in the CSS file?...and that if I cash that CCS in my manifest, all images will come with it...and therefore there is no need to chash each one as I though? uhhh?

Comment: I meant in the CSS file: jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css

Comment: All the svg icons are included in the CSS file so providing you only need to support browsers that support inline svg then you don't need to list any of the images in your manifest. If you do need to support other browsers then you need to include the png files in your manifest.

Comment: first step- combine all images to one sprite, you can use tools like [spritecow](http://www.spritecow.com/) to generate a CSS easily, for each one of the url(...) paths in jQuery's CSS. third step is to convert the big image to BASE64 using [abluestar](http://www.abluestar.com/utilities/encode_base64/), 4th step, is replacing the path with the BASE64 string wrapped in " or '. your CSS is offline now. fyi: your web-server will GZIP the CSS so it won't be "huge".. another thing- you may use the local-storage to store stuff around, to avoid requests.. (find examples on my website).